# How to use PROGMEM in a .h/.cpp file instead of a .ino file?

Tags: programming, progmem

I want to use a lot of `.h`/`.cpp` files to be used by my `ino` sketch.
In one of these .cpp files (and later more) I want to use constant arrays (like lookup tables). To save SRAM I want to use `PROGMEM`.

What worked before in the Ino sketch is:

```
const uint8_t _red[]   PROGMEM = { 0, 9, 10, 220, 230, 240, 255 };
```

But when I put the line above in a `.h` or `.cpp` file I get the error:

```
Par.h:13:25: error: expected initializer before 'PROGMEM'
```

Should I include something or can't I use `PROGMEM` in a `.h`/`.cpp` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the answer.

Include:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
```

**Update**

See also remark of AnT, which is a more generic (and in most cases better solution):

```
#include "Arduino.h"
```

(just to help others with the same problem).

Comment: ... that is If you have a reason not to include `<Arduino.h>`. But if you do include `<Arduino.h>`, then `<avr/pgmspace.h>` is included with it anyway.

Comment: @AnT Thanks for that remark; I added it to the solution (I really thought I tried it before and didn't work, but it does).